# Git GUI on Windows: merging conflicts

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-gui

I am fluent with Git on the command line but for a specific project, I need to show others how to do things exclusively in the GUI environment. We are using Git for Windows (available at https://git-scm.com/download/win).

I created a file and added to the repository. Then had another user modify the file and push it. I also modified the file, then I fetched the repository from origin, and used "Merge > Local Merge" menu to show how Git GUI finds the conflicts.

Then I manually edited the text file and resolved the conflict by cherry-picking some of my changes and some of those by the other user. At this stage, if it was command line I would do `git add`. In the GUI you are supposed to do the same thing using the "Stage Changed" button, I presume, but when I press the button it doesn't actually stage the changed file.

I cannot find any online documentation for the GUI program that discusses merge conflict resolution. Can anyone please tell me what the next step would be in the GUI environment?

Comment: My better advice: use GitExtensions instead. Easier to use...

Comment: Good advice. I will look into it. I will still leave this open though, in case someone knows the answer for Git for Windows.

Comment: And you can even use a good merge tool like p4merge that will easy a lot of merge ;-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found the answer. As annoying as it is, when you are doing anything other than conflict resolution, the `Stage Changed` button does what the `git add` command would do. But if you are resolving conflicts, you should not use that button (it actually doesn't work); instead you should use the following menu: `Commit > Stage To Commit`. The keyboard shortcut is `CTRL+T`.

In fact the `Stage Changed` button is equivalent to the menu option `Commit > Stage Changed Files to Commit`.

Comment: What a terrible UX :-(

Comment: two years later and this solved the same problem for me. Thank you!

Comment: ... And yet another year-plus later, still relevant. Saved my day!

Comment: Jumping on the band wagon a few months hence :)

Comment: Thank you all! Glad to see that my "discovery" has changed other people's lives :)

Comment: Saved me after hours of fighting with git. Thank you!

Comment: Four++  years later, still relevant ;)

Comment: 5 years later still solve my noob problem..ty brother!

Comment: 6.4 years later, just saved me today

Comment: 2024 and this fix still works, this means no improvement on Git GUI ?